# WP_Media_List_Table{} для пользовательской таксономии

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть пользовательская таксономия "Галерея" созданная вручную.
Скажите пожалуйста есть ли способ заменить обычный класс таблицы WP_List_Table{} на WP_Media_List_Table{} или хотя бы статьи по работе с данным классом, чтобы я мог сам вывести все посты данной таксономии?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можете использовать его. Вам нужно просто сделать класс и наследовать `WP_Media_List_Table`, затем переопределить методы, например `prepare_items` и описать все логику:

```
class Gallery_List_Table extends WP_Media_List_Table {

    public function prepare_items() {
        
    }
}
```

Затем там, где вам используйте метод `display`, чтобы переопределить метод:

`( new Gallery_List_Table )->display();`